# ng-token-auth, ionic, devise_token_auth; token get lost randomly in xhr request

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ruby-on-rails-4, devise-token-auth

I have inherited a Ionic app which uses `ng-token-auth`+`devise_token_auth` to handle the authentication and the session between front and back.

What happens is quite strange. Sometimes (specially with slow connections) the request (or the response) get lost and after that I get only `401` http errors.

I know that that everytime I send a request the token expires, but when the `xhr` request is cancelled (by the server I suppose, or by the browser, I don't know) the token is expired without having been replaced by the new one generated by `devise_token_auth` gem.

I know Rails but I'm not familiar with Angular, neither Ionic and I don't know exactly where to look.

After reading a lot of SO answers where noone seems having my problem (which happens locally and in staging/production), I checked the following

- `storage` is set as `localStorage`.
- `config.batch_request_buffer_throttle = 20.seconds`
- there is no pattern between cancelled requests, sometimes I perform get for the username, sometimes a post or a put to a comment.
- Is not a CORS problem because it would happen always or never. (moreover I'm using a proxy as explained in [ionic blog](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/))
- Maybe it could be related to [provisional headers](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=294891) chrome bug. But, how can I be sure?

What puzzles my is that it happens only **sometimes** and not always. (and there are no errors in the backend)

The only workaround I have found [in the devise_token_auth documentation](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) is change `config.change_headers_on_each_request` to `false` avoiding in this way the regeneration of the token.

But I don't like this solution because I think it hides the real problem in an insecure way instead of solving the token loss. Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? I have same kind of a problem..

Comment: Sadly not. :( But I discovered that it was due a failing request in the middle that caused the token to be discarded. But we kept the workaround with `false` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Kindly, please check this thing:**

- **Version**: which version of this gem (and [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth), [jToker](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/j-toker) or [Angular2-Token](https://github.com/neroniaky/angular-token) if applicable) are you using?
- **Request and response headers**: these can be found in the "Network" tab of your browser's web inspector.
- **Rails Stacktrace**: this can be found in the log/development.log of your API.
- **Environmental Info**: How is your application different from the [reference implementation](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth_demo)?

  This may include (but is not limited to) the following details:

  **Routes**: are you using some crazy namespace, scope, or constraint?

  **Gems**: are you using MongoDB, Grape, RailsApi, ActiveAdmin, etc.?

  **Custom Overrides**: what have you done in terms of [custom controller overrides]
  [5](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/#custom-controller-overrides)?

  **Custom Frontend**: are you using  [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth), [jToker](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/j-toker), [Angular2-
  Token](https://github.com/neroniaky/angular-token), or something else?